# How to bold a variable?

Tags: php

How can I have text within a php variable be bold??

```
function show_balance_header ($balance, $currency)
{
    (string)$display_output = null;
    $display_output = fees_main::display_amount(abs($balance), $currency, true);
    return $display_output;
}
```

I want to bold `$balance`. Is there an easy way or do I need to edit `display_amount`?

I've tried doing this:

`"<b>".$balance"</b>"` but this did not get the correct variable,

thanks in advance!!

Comment: @AlvinWong lol originally downvoted my answer with that suggestion then made the same one as a comment later

Comment: Since `fees_main::display_amount` operates on `$balance` and gives the output you'll have to make it bold in there

Comment: Does the variable `balance` contains something ?

Comment: @LucM yes, balance contains an integer

Comment: @Raeki yes because I thought the answer should be something much complicated (because `$balance` is a number and need to be passed to `abs`), then I noticed the missing `.`. Fixing that won't fix the major problem but you're not wrong anyway, so I un-downvoted your answer :P

Comment: @AlvinWong haha yeah no probs after he clarified I specified my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is to edit the inner function display_amount using Raeki's suggestion, for future questions, i think you must edit the inner-most function as only editing function show_balance_header did not get the correct variable

Answer (score 5):

Needs to be `"<b>" . $balance . "</b>"`. Concatenate `<b>` to `$balance` and concatenate again to `</b>`

---

**Edit**:
Assuming this does the printing/formatting: `fees_main::display_amount(abs($balance)`

You want `fees_main::display_amount('<b>' . abs($balance) . '</b>', $currency, true)`.
abs($balance) gets the absolute value as a number, and the concatenation (explained above) automatically casts them to strings. The rest of the parameters are passed the same way (unmodified, unbolded).

`(string)$display_output = null;` is unnecessary

Comment: @AlvinWong His doesn't have the second period/concatenation.

Comment: ah sorry, forget it in the post, no this was what i did and it did not work

Comment: @spaceranger Well how are you using it? Your current code doesn't actually include code to print it.

Answer (score 0):

On your element html, example:

```
<p> text <?php echo "<b>{$balance}</b>"; ?> text</p>
```