# How to make variable printed bold when using a Facebookrequest for "POST"

Tags: php

Ho to make `$price` to be printed bold on the following
I have tried the `<b>` and `<string>` but they will not let the price displayed correctly

```
$message .= ' - ' . $price;
```

I am echoing the following

```
$attachment = array(
            'access_token' => $this->config->get('fb_auto_post_access_token'),
            'message'      => $message,
```

and

```
$fb_request = new FacebookRequest($fb_session, 'POST', '/' . $this->config->get('fb_auto_post_page_id') . '/feed', $attachment);
```

Using `<b>` and `<Strong>` will not work as it will show `<b>$price</b>` or `<strong>$price</strong>`

Thank you

Comment: Is the output as HTML? So, `strong` or `b` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bold a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681435/how-to-bold-a-variable)

Comment: You didn't provide a real example of what you tried.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `<b>` tag to the beginning and end like so:

`$message .= ' - <b>' . $price . '</b>';`

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Comment: when I use this, it prints "<b>$29.99</b>"

Comment: @Schwann and your echoing out the message?

Comment: @Schwann There must be something else you are doing because I have tried and it does echo out properly

Comment: I echo this $attachment = array(
   'access_token' => $this->config->get('fb_auto_post_access_token'),
   'message'      => $message,

Comment: @Schwann you are echoing the array? or are you doing `echo $attachment['message'];` ?

Comment: this is how it is posted,  $fb_request = new FacebookRequest($fb_session, 'POST', '/' . $this->config->get('fb_auto_post_page_id') . '/feed', $attachment);

Comment: @Schwann so you are using a facebookrequest to post a feed with the message? If so I believe you cannot make the feed bold, they most likely convert the html characters so they cannot be ran

Answer (score 1):

Making an element bold cannot be done with pure PHP. You would need either to echo a `<b>` tag (`echo "<b>" . $bold . "</b>";`), or more preferably, use CSS.

First, create a CSS style that applies the `bold` font-weight:

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then you can either echo this styling when **output** your PHP variable:

```
echo "<div class='bold'>$bold</div>";
```

Or even more preferably, craft your HTML **around** the variable:

```
<div class="bold"><?php echo $bold; ?></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)